# Find out if pipe's read end is currently blocking

Tags: c, unix, posix, pipe

I'm trying to find out if a child process is waiting for user input (without parsing its output). Is it possible, in C on Unix, to determine if a pipe's read end currently has a read() call blocking?

The thing is, I have no control over the programs exec'd in the child processes. They print all kinds of verbose garbage which I would usually want to redirect to /dev/null. Occasionally though one will prompt the user for something. (With the prompt having no reliable format.) So my idea was:

- In a loop:

  - Drain child's stdout, append it to a temporary buffer.
  - Check (no idea how) if the child is asking for user input, in which case the buffer is printed to stdout.
- When the child exits, throw away the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, I have no control over the programs exec'd in the child processes. They print all kinds of verbose garbage which I would usually want to redirect to /dev/null. Occasionally though one will prompt the user for something. (With the prompt having no reliable format.) So my idea was:

- In a loop:

  - Drain child's stdout, append it to a temporary buffer.
  - Check (no idea how) if the child is asking for user input, in which case the buffer is printed to stdout.
- When the child exits, throw away the buffer.

Comment: The trouble is, then, that you've no real way to determine what to supply as input to the child, either.  I'm not even sure that 'expect' can help - though it is pretty flexible about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have these options:

- if you know that the child will need certain input (such as shell that will read a command), just write to a pipe
- if you assume the child won't read anything usually, but may do it sometimes, you probably need something like job control in the shell (use a terminal for communication with the child, use process groups and TIOCSPGRP ioctl on the terminal to get the child to the background; the child will get SIGTTIN when it tries to read from the terminal, and you can wait() for that). This is how bash handles things like "`(sleep 10; read a;)&`"
- if you don't know what to write, or you have more possibilities, you will have to parse the output

Answer (score 1):

That sounds as if you were trying to supervise dpkg where occasionally some post-inst script queries the admin whether it may override some config file.

Anyway, you may want to look at how strace works:

```
strace -f -etrace=read your.program
```

Of course you need to keep track of which fds are the pipes you write about, but you probably need only stdin, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's true: For example, *right before* calling read() on the reader side, the pipe would have a reader that isn't actually reading.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically just write to the pipe, or use select or poll.  If you need a handshake mechanism you can do that out of band various ways or come up with and in-band protocol.

I don't know if there is a built-in way to know if a reader on the other end is blocking.  Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly, you can not have a pipe with no reader which means that you have either a read(2) or a select(2) syscal pending at all time.

Comment: That's not really true, you can have a pipe without reader. And "having reader" means "there is a process that has the pipe open()-ed for reading", it doesn't have anything to do with select() or read().